# how to make Julia detect incompatible types on assignment?

Tags: julia

Sorry for the basic question, googling was not too useful so far.

I am a newbie. I'd like to ask if it is possible to have Julia automatically detect incompatible types on assignments.

For example, when I write

```
julia> x=10;
julia> typeof(x)
Int32

julia> y=9.0;    
julia> typeof(y)
Float64

julia> x=y // I'd like this to generate an error or a warning at least
9.0

julia> typeof(x) // do not want automatic type conversion
Float64
```

I found that if change the assignment to

```
julia> (x=y)::Int32
ERROR: type: typeassert: expected Int32, got Float64
```

But I do not want to write this all the time, and want Julia to automatically detect this. 
I tried to do declarations like this below, but I seem to be doing something wrong.

```
julia> x::Int32=10;
julia> y::Float64=9.0
ERROR: type: typeassert: expected Float64, got Int32
```

For example, in Java, this generates a compile error:

```
public class App{   
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int x=10;
        double y=9.0;
        x=y;
    }
}
error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int x=y;
```

What do I need to change to make this happen? do I need to declare x,y with the correct type before? how? I am using Julia 0.3 on Linux.

Comment: See [Julia's type system](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/types/) for more details, but "Describing Julia in the lingo of type systems, it is: dynamic, nominative and parametric."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Values represented by variables can be qualified to always have a particular type, and incompatible values will be checked, but the check for this violation occurs at run time.  From the [documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.2/manual/types/#type-declarations):

> When appended to a variable in a statement context, the :: operator means something a bit different: it declares the variable to always have the specified type, like a type declaration in a statically-typed language such as C. Every value assigned to the variable will be converted to the declared type using the convert function.

here is a important caveat, though

> Currently, type declarations cannot be used in global scope, e.g. in the REPL, since Julia does not yet have constant-type globals.

So your experiment does not work because you're using globals.  However, type assertions using variables scoped in a function do.

So taking your example

#### Case I

```
julia> main()=(x::Int64=10;y::Float64=9.0;x=y)
main (generic function with 1 method)

julia> main()
9.0
```

That looks like the wrong thing happened, but the result of a function is last expression evaluated.  So in Case I, the assignment expression returns a *Float64* value, though ***x*** is still implicitly assigned *9.0* converted to an *Int64* or *9*.  But in Case II, the last expression is simply ***x*** which is *Int64*.

#### Case II

```
julia> main()=(x::Int64=10;y::Float64=9.0;x=y;x)
main (generic function with 1 method)

julia> main()
9

julia> typeof(main())
Int64
```

When ***y*** takes on a value that can't be [converted](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/conversion-and-promotion/) without loss to *Int64* an error is thrown

#### Case III

```
julia> main()=(x::Int64=10;y::Float64=9.9;x=y;x)
main (generic function with 1 method)

julia> main()
ERROR: InexactError()
 in main at none:1
```

### The Guts

You can use the function ***code_typed*** to see what is going to more precisely.  Consider the following:

```
julia> f(y::Float64)=(x::Int64=y)
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> code_typed(f,(Float64,))
1-element Array{Any,1}:
 :($(Expr(:lambda, {:y}, {{:x},{{:y,Float64,0},{:x,Int64,18}},{}}, :(begin  # none, line 1:
        x = top(typeassert)(top(box)(Int64,top(checked_fptosi)(Int64,y::Float64))::Int64,Int64)::Int64
        return y::Float64
    end::Float64))))

julia> f(y::Float64)=(x::Int64=y;x)
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> code_typed(f,(Float64,))
1-element Array{Any,1}:
 :($(Expr(:lambda, {:y}, {{:x},{{:y,Float64,0},{:x,Int64,18}},{}}, :(begin  # none, line 1:
         x = top(typeassert)(top(box)(Int64,top(checked_fptosi)(Int64,y::Float64))::Int64,Int64)::Int64
        return x::Int64
    end::Int64))))
```

Comment: thanks. But I do not understand this difference `main()=(x::Int64=10;y::Float64=9.0;x=y); typeof(main())` which returns
`Float64` while `main()=(x::Int64=10;y::Float64=9.0;x=y;x); typeof(main())` now returns `Int64` ? Should not `x=y` evaluate first, then the result of the expression which is `x` be returned from main()? Then why does it give different result from writing `x=y;x` ? If you think this should be a separate question, I can post it.

Comment: I also think the second case you showed above should have returned an error. I do not see a difference between `y::Float64=9.9` and `y::Float64=9.0` in terms of typing. Both are incompatible types with `x` type, then it should have given this error in both cases. That is what I'd like Julia to have done.

Comment: @Nasser Julia does not prevent variable assignment solely due to type difference.  I've added some additional explanation.  Hope that helps.